# How to match the name column with result after classification scikit-learn

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn

This is an example of my data:

```
filename,2,3,4,5,6,7,class    
a.txt,0,0,0,0,0,0,0    
b.txt,0,0,0,0,0,1,0    
c.txt,0,0,0,0,1,0,0    
d.txt,1,0,1,0,0,1,1
```

When I train my data, I just use the columns from 2 -> 7 as input, class as output. But when I test the model after it trained and save, I need to know that which files are belong to which class. I mean like how to know d.txt is class 1.
I use pandas to import the data from .csv file, I use train set and test set in 2 different csv files. In the train phase, I uses columns 2-7 as input, and column class as target, these columns are numerical. The filename class is just text. In the test phase, I need to know the filename with the predicted class. But I don't know how to do that.

Thanks

P/s: I used MLP,SVM, NB as classifier.

Comment: Is your data separated by dashes? Each dash separates a column? You might want to check your data since the number of columns in the header doesn't match the rest of the file. Additionaly, suppose my classifier outputs **0**, how are you going to distinguish from `"a.txt"`, `"b.txt"` and `"c.txt"`?

Comment: Normally you'd use `svm.predict()` and pass in the feature vector, but I wouldn't know for sure without seeing your code.

Comment: @yellow01 no, just by commas, I just show that to easier to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in `.csv` format:

```
filename,2,3,4,5,6,7,class
a.txt,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
b.txt,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
c.txt,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
d.txt,1,0,1,0,0,1,1
```

You can output the corresponding filename to a predicted class using:

```
features=[1,0,1,0,0,1] #input
output=clf.predict([features])[0] #predicted class
print(df[df["class"]==output]["filename"]) #corresponding filename
```

Note that in your example you're facing the problem where the amount of features is greater than the amount of examples, therefore the classifier may deteriorate.

Hopefully you just gave a sample of your data. In this case you're likely to be good. Just watch out for what classifier to use.

Full code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm

df=pd.read_csv('file.csv')

X = df.iloc[:,1:7].values
y = df.iloc[:,7:8].values
clf = svm.SVC() #using SVM as classifier
clf.fit(X, y)

features=[1,0,1,0,0,1]
output=clf.predict([features])[0]
print(df[df["class"]==output]["filename"])
```